# Protractor testing: How to set the value of text elements in a login form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am writing tests in Protractor for an Angular app. I want to fill out a login form and submit it.

How can I do this? I have got this far, but I don't know how to set the value of the email and password fields.

```
describe('The dashboard', function() {
  ptor = protractor.getInstance();

  beforeEach(function() {
    ptor.get('#/dashboard');
    var email = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.model('email'));
    var password = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.model('password'));
    var submit = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.tagName('button'));
    // Fill out the form?
    submit.click();
  });

  it('has a heading', function() {
    heading = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.tagName('h1'));
    expect(heading.getText()).toEqual('My Dashboard');
  });
});
```

Comment: Figured it out: `email.sendKeys('myemail@myemail.com')`

Comment: You might consider selecting oine of the answers. Or add your own answer and accet that. After all the Answer is answered.

Answer (score 85):

Just for the benefit of anyone who found this via Google, the answer is:

```
email.sendKeys('myemail@myemail.com');
password.sendKeys('mypassword');
```

Comment: keep in mind that this appends the string to the value in input, if you don't want to append, just clear() the input before you sendKeys

Answer (score 26):

you can use

```
email.clear().sendKeys('myemail@myemail.com');
password.clear().sendKeys('mypassword');
```

Comment: please explain your answer how it will work or add essential part of answer.

Comment: First it clears the data in text box and then add the exact value mentioned given.

Comment: Actually, clear() returns a promise so if you want to clear the input first it should be email.clear().then(() => {email.sendKeys('myemail@myemail.com')});

Answer (score 11):

In addition to [shruti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5366443/shruti-dalvi) and [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194000/richard),

To ensure the input is empty or cleared, use the **clear** method which returns a **Promise**. Resolve the promise with **sendKeys** method on your input. This is helpful if you have pre-populated your input with default values.

Async/Await:

```
async fillInEmail() { 
  await email.clear(); 
  email.sendKeys('myemail@myemail.com'); 
}
async fillInPassword() { 
  await password.clear(); 
  password.sendKeys('mypassword'); 
}
```

ES6:

```
email.clear().then(() => {
    email.sendKeys('myemail@myemail.com');
});

password.clear().then(() => {
    password.sendKeys('mypassword');
});
```

Before ES6:

```
email.clear().then(function() {
    email.sendKeys('myemail@myemail.com');
});

password.clear().then(function() {
    password.sendKeys('mypassword');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per above answers , you can use sendkeys in most cases .
If that doesn't work, you can inject the text to the element using Javascript.

```
var locatorid='datepicker1';
var val= '12/31/2019';

//without parameterized
browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('datepicker1').value='10/21/2019'");

//After parameterized
browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('"+locatorid+"').value='"+val+"'");
browser.sleep(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about xpath?

I create a button like bellow:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="model.password" name="password" type="text" #passcode="ngModel" required>
</ion-input>
```

And set the value using

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@name="password"]/input')).sendKeys('PASSWORD')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var searchComment = element(by.name("customTextField"));
searchComment.sendKeys("france").then(function() {
    next()
});
```

Comment: Pl add some explanation to your answer