# Insert text in a "paste-like" fashion

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I've seen another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192689/protractor-testing-how-to-set-the-value-of-text-elements-in-a-login-form) to a related question, however, what I'm looking to do is different.

Is there a way to insert text into a text box, in a manner similar to pasting from a copy buffer?

We're doing a lot of edge-case testing (e.g. what happens when I enter 2001 characters into a field validating on a max of 2000). `sendKeys` works perfectly fine, but it enters text how a human would (one character at a time) rather than bulk insert.

Answer (score 0):

you could use selenium webdriver for that by first sending the keys by sending keys and then copy pasting it back in or by using a secondary input or element with text that you copy that is not restricted on 2000 chars to test the scenario where you paste 2001 chars in:

```
elem = find_element_by_name("our_element")
elem.send_keys("bar") // send keys to the input first 2000 chars for instance if you want you can put this in another element which is not restricted on 2000 chars

elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') select all
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c') copy
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v') paste
```

Comment: Cool suggestion! Unfortunately I don't think this will work for me because the tests are in separate cases and I'd rather not have the state bleed across.