# Angular e2e Test dealing with image buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple login form wich I desire to test with protractor in angular

I should enter my password using a component like a virtual keyboard rendered with images and I need to enter 1234. The thing is that is really easy to use the robot from e2e to press those buttons BUT my virtual keyboard renders the keys in a random way, so I don't know where my 1 2 3 4 keys are since they are not in the same position always.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Why do you have to use the virtual keyboard? Can't you just set the input values directly? like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20200069/4963159

Comment: I guess if you really do need the virtual keyboard, you could scan the DOM to find the element you are looking for (using IDs or values)

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi I'm render values from json object. This values are images in base 64. I do not have any extra information.

Comment: I see, so if I understand correctly, you get a list of keys from a json object and then use ng-repeat to show the list of keys?
If this understanding is correct, then your options are the following:
- add an index to the json array that you get back, and then use orderBy in the ngRepeat
- create a custom filter if there is any other information that you could use
- define a new object that maps the order of the keys (not best solution)

If you can post the JSON for the keys, together with the html/js snippets I could help further