# Protractor(angular testing framework): How to delete multiple attachments/documents from an input field (type=file) that have been uploaded

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

I have uploaded some documents in input field and want to delete it by writing test case for it using protractor(angular e2e framework). How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you say delete from the input field do you mean to simply reset the value of that field?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192689/protractor-testing-how-to-set-the-value-of-text-elements-in-a-login-form/20200069), and you can reset the value of input fields by using `clear()`:

```
var documentsField = protractor.getInstance().findElement(protractor.By.model('documents'));
documentsField.clear();
```

You can learn more about clear() in the [Protractor API docs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.clear).